# How does a website detect devices on your local network

Tags: web-services, networking, service-discovery

I have a HD Home Run device, and when I go to http://my.hdhomerun.com/ I am able to see the HD Home Run device I have listed on my network listed along with the local IP address of the unit.  How is this possible?  My goal is to implement something similar in a product that I am developing.

I did some digging and found that it is able to generate the data from a json file at http://ipv4-api.hdhomerun.com/discover, but was not able to trace how this json file was generated.

Answer (score 0):

When a device connects to another node or machine it automatically sends machine details to help with compatibility.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more please?  Are you saying the HD Home Run device is sending details that is sees on the network to accomplish this?  If so, where are you saying it sending the data?